# cant seem to upload image to database

Tags: mysql, uploading

what i have on the webpage didnt want to show my entire web page but if i have to i will. The site just goes back to the edit-profile.php and doesnt actually upload the image to the database when i do it outside of the web page in a dummy page it works. but when i add it into my web page it stops working

```
 <form action="/sub/test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="title">Title:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="64"><br><br>

   <label for="photo">Photo:</label><br>
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"><br><br>

  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
test.php:
  <?php
   $db_host = ''; // don't forget to change 
   $db_user = ''; 
   $db_pwd = '';

   $database = '';
   $table = '';
// use the same name as SQL table

   $password = '123';
// simple upload restriction,
// to disallow uploading to everyone


   if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

   if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// This function makes usage of
// $_GET, $_POST, etc... variables
// completly safe in SQL queries
   function sql_safe($s)
    {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $s = stripslashes($s);

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
   } 

// If user pressed submit in one of the forms
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    // cleaning title field
    $title = trim(sql_safe($_POST['title']));

    if ($title == '') // if title is not set
        $title = '(empty title)';// use (empty title) string

    if ($_POST['password'] != $password)  // cheking passwors
        $msg = 'Error: wrong upload password';
    else
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['photo']))
        {
            @list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']              ['tmp_name']);
            // Get image type.
            // We use @ to omit errors

            if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type
                $ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers
            elseif ($imtype == 2)
                $ext="jpeg";
            elseif ($imtype == 1)
                $ext="gif";
            else
                $msg = 'Error: unknown file format';

            if (!isset($msg)) // If there was no error
            {
                $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
                $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
                // Preparing data to be used in MySQL query

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table}
                                SET ext='$ext', title='$title',
                                    data='$data'");

                $msg = 'Success: image uploaded';
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['title']))      // isset(..title) needed
            $msg = 'Error: file not loaded';// to make sure we've using
                                            // upload form, not form
                                            // for deletion


        if (isset($_POST['del'])) // If used selected some photo to delete
        {                         // in 'uploaded images form';
            $id = intval($_POST['del']);
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id=$id");
            $msg = 'Photo deleted';
        }
    }
}
elseif (isset($_GET['show']))
{


List item

---------

 $id = intval($_GET['show']);

       $result = mysql_query("SELECT ext, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(image_time), data
                             FROM {$table}
                            WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1");

          if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
           die('no image');

          list($ext, $image_time, $data) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

          $send_304 = false;
           if (php_sapi_name() == 'apache') {
        // if our web server is apache
        // we get check HTTP
        // If-Modified-Since header
        // and do not send image
        // if there is a cached version

        $ar = apache_request_headers();
        if (isset($ar['If-Modified-Since']) && // If-Modified-Since should exists
            ($ar['If-Modified-Since'] != '') && // not empty
            (strtotime($ar['If-Modified-Since']) >= $image_time)) // and grater than
            $send_304 = true;                                     // image_time
    }


    if ($send_304)
    {
        // Sending 304 response to browser
        // "Browser, your cached version of image is OK
        // we're not sending anything new to you"
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $ts).' GMT', true, 304);

        exit(); // bye-bye
    }

    // outputing Last-Modified header
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $image_time).' GMT',
            true, 200);

    // Set expiration time +1 year
    // We do not have any photo re-uploading
    // so, browser may cache this photo for quite a long time
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',  $image_time + 86400*365).' GMT',
            true, 200);

    // outputing HTTP headers
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
    header("Content-type: image/{$ext}");

    // outputing image
    echo $data;
    exit();
}
?>

<input type="submit" value="upload">
```

Comment: You should add some tags for the language you're using and explain the steps you've taken to find out why it isn't woriking.  Are you sure your page is connecting to the database?  Are you seeing any errors in your browser dev tools?

Comment: there isn't a error it looks like it goes threw the webpage flashes but when i check the database nothing is there. it doesnt even seem like its actually doing anything